# Pass value of inputfield to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, inputfield

I have created a Vf page from which i need to fetch the value of new subcription type. I'm not able to pass the picklist value to the controller for creating a new subscription. I would really appreciate your help here.

This is my Vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Subscription__c" extensions="subscriptionController">
    <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="This Subscription" id="this_subscription">

         <!-- Terms List -->
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Subscription__c }" var="ts">

             <apex:column title="Update subscription to">
                <apex:facet name="header">Update subscription to</apex:facet>
                <apex:inputField value="{! ts.update_Subscription__c }"/>
             </apex:column>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
         <apex:commandButton action="{!cloneWithTerms}" value="Clone with Terms" immediate="true"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

This is the controller:

```
private Subscription__c subscription {get;set;}
private Subscription__c oldSub;
private Subscription__c newSub;

private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

public subscriptionController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.subscription = (Subscription__c)stdController.getRecord();
    this.stdController = stdController;

    oldSub = [SELECT Id, Name, Contact__c, Startdate__c, Enddate__c,   update_Subscription__c FROM Subscription__c WHERE Id = :stdController.getId()];
}

public PageReference cloneWithTerms() {

    try{         
        // new subscription with updated 'type' preference
        newSub = new Subscription__c();
        newSub.Contact__c = oldSub.Contact__c;
        newSub.Startdate__c = Date.today();
        newSub.Enddate__c = oldSub.Enddate__c;
        // Determine new subscriptiontype
        if (this.subscription.update_Subscription__c == '6M1') {            newSub.X6M1__c = TRUE;
        } else if (this.subscription.update_Subscription__c == '6M2') {     newSub.X6M2__c = TRUE;
        } else if (this.subscription.update_Subscription__c == '6MO') {     newSub.X6MO__c = TRUE;
        } else if (this.subscription.update_Subscription__c == '12M1') {    newSub.X12M1__c = TRUE;
        } else if (this.subscription.update_Subscription__c == '12M2') {    newSub.X12M2__c = TRUE;
        } else if (this.subscription.update_Subscription__c == '12MO') {    newSub.X12MO__c = TRUE;
        }
        insert newSub ;

    }catch(exception e){                
    }

    PageReference page = new Pagereference('/'+newSub.Id);
    page.setRedirect(true);
    return page;
}
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Can you use <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!subscription}" var="ts">

Answer (score 1):

The `immediate=true` processes the action without any validation and thus does not pass anything to the controller (setters do not fire). It just executes the action.

It is a common stumbling block for those new to visual force.

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
         <apex:commandButton action="{!cloneWithTerms}" value="Clone with Terms"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

As an aside if you want to prevent a page refresh simply add:

`rerender=""`

and if you actually want to rerender and do a partial page refresh then add the appropriate id to it:

`rerender="some_element_id"`

Answer (score 0):

Currently I run a query in the constructor because I'm not able to access this methods query results in the pagereference:

```
private String sortOrder = 'Collectiondate__c';
public List<Term__c> getTerms() {

List<Term__c> results = Database.query(
    'SELECT Id, Term__c FROM Term__c WHERE Collectiondate__c >= TODAY ' +
    'ORDER BY ' + sortOrder
);
return results;
}
```

Any suggestions on this?